# Iphone SQLite base encode

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

Is it possible to encode sqllite base for my app? In my application bundle I have *.sqlite file with the base and I need to deny access for that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean encryption?

You could do this in 2 (probably more) ways that I can think of now:

1. You encrypt the database file file with some encryption software, decrypt it at runtime and store the decrypted database file in the application directory. Then when you are about to exit your app, you encrypt and store the encrypted file and remove the decrypted one.
2. You could try and compile the [SQLite Encryption Extension](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html). I know people have managed to get the full text search extension working, so you could take a look on how they did it.

Comment: Hi, I'm considering to use SQLite Encryption Extension to handle encrypted data in my database. Does SEE it supports full-text search out of the box? You wrote that "people have managed to get the full text search extension working". What kind of effort it requires to get full-text search working?

Comment: @webdevbyjoss You could either compile your own sqlite with ths FTS extension or try to add the extension to the apple provided one. I know I saw somebody that manades to do the latter (which saves you some memory and application size), but I can not find it now using google.